# Файл конфигурации clang-format, перенос запятой на новую строку

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать конфиг для clang-format, чтобы перенос **длинных** строк осуществлялся вместе с запятой, а не после? Соответствующего параметра в clang-format я не нашел.

Для примера есть исходная строка:

```
unsigned long long int Fooooooooooooo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Если строка с кодом имеет длину больше чем N clang-format разобьёт её следующим образом:

```
unsigned long long int Fooooooooooooo(int a, int b, int c,
        int d, int e, int f, int g)
{
    return 0;
}
```

А хочется чтобы разбил так:

```
unsigned long long int Fooooooooooooo(int a, int b, int c
        , int d, int e, int f, int g)
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Самое важное** в данном случае - **положение запятой** при переносе строки (после int c). Всё остальное я настрою под свои нужды. Положение запятой - критично, т.к. есть code-style, да и сам привык так писать.

Буду рад вашим советам!

Comment: Возможно поможет `BreakBeforeInheritanceComma`

Comment: @diraria, к сожалению параметр **BreakBeforeInheritanceComma** не спас